# Reusing an Initialisation Vector After X Amount of Times

Tags: security, encryption, vector, cryptography, initialization

I'm building a piece of software that looks to send messages to a server.

I'm limited to using a random number between 1 and 1,000 each time for the IV.

When debating with a colleague about how many times I can send messages before the IV is reused, he argues that after just 32 random numbers, there's a greater than 50% chance that my IV will be duplicated.

How is this possible? I thought that I would be able to use it at least 500 times without there being a 50% chance of duplicate.

Of course, after the second time, there's always a chance the number will be picked that has been reused, but we are talking abut at least a 50% chance here in terms of stats.

Can somebody explain if he is right and how that's possible?

Comment: Yes, he's right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem (and see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack#WEP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Each time you pick a new random number the chance of hitting a number you already picked increases. If you have picked 10 numbers, the chance for picking one you already have used is 1%. When you have used 20 numbers, you are at 2%. These numbers adds up pretty quick.